# android 8.0 api level 27 Media recorder start failed with audio source voice call

Tags: android

I used media Recorder library to record voice call and it's working well in almost android version except for android Oreo 8.0  API level 27.
when I use the audio source  VOICE_CALL I got run time exception start failed 
and when I use audio source VOICE_COMMUNICATION I didn't get the sound of the other party I got my voice only.

```
//            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
            recorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource);


            recorder.setOutputFormat(AudioFormate);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoding);

            recorder.setOutputFile(down);
     recorder.start();
```

Could you please help

Comment: i have this problem too ,,, do you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Capturing from `VOICE_CALL` source requires the `Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` permission. This permission is reserved for use by system components and is not available to third-party applications.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_CALL) in the official docs it is mentioned that `VOICE_CALL` is only for system apps.